# Matlab matrix image conversion

Tags: matlab, imaging

I am working with MATLAB for a school project. The assignment is to import a matrix file supplied to me, and display it as a new figure using `image`. Right now, I can make an image with

```
m1 = load('matrix1.csv'); image(m1)
```

But the image is rotated to the right. How do I rotate it so the image is presented horizontally rather than vertically?

Comment: ...and your question is ?

Comment: Eternal September. So it begins. Heroes of the MATLAB tag, beware...

Comment: How would you write the code using the image command?

Comment: I figured out how to do it, except the image that matlab makes is horizontal not vertical

Comment: this is the code m1 = load('matrix1.csv');
                 image(m1)

Comment: @user2762870 - Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a great community to be apart of, and we MATLAB regulars would love to help you solve future problems. But we need you to help us help you. Please read up on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and you can help make our community an even better resource.

Comment: I am sorry for being so vague let me try again. I am trying to turn a matrix into an image using only the image command, now I figured out how to do it the only problem is that the image is rotated to the right. How would I be able to fix this? Here is the code I have thus far  m1 = load('matrix1.csv');
image(m1)

Comment: @user2762870, have you tried searching for an answer? Try googling "matlab rotate image" and see if someone has already asked (and answered) your question before. ;)

Comment: @user2762870 - Based on your comments, you are using StackOverflow as a forum, where free-flowing dialog takes place. SO is a Q&A-driven site, **not** a forum. I took the liberty of editing your question based on your comments, and hopefully these edits are implemented shortly. Please read the [About Page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for SO to get a feel for what SO is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely arising from the fact that there are different ways of storing data (row-major vs. column-major). In this case, your .csv file clearly is not in the format you are expecting. The easiest thing to do is to simply transpose the matrix containing your data:

```
m1 = m1';
image(m1);
```

If there is something crazier going on and this flips it the wrong way (I don't think this should be the case, but you never know), you can try the rotate command: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html